# Python Panda read_excel - User input for part of io name

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file-io, user-input

I have the following code:

```
filename=input("Name of file?")
sheet=input("Name of sheet?")

df=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Path/JAN.xls', \
             sheetname=sheet,\
             header=0,\
             parse_cols="C:BD",\
             na_values='T')
```

I would like the "JAN" part of file name to be changeable according to user input before the file runs. For example, I have other files in the same directory labeled as "/JAN", "/FEB","/MAR", etc. How do I add a variable that can change the file io depending on the user input?

Comment: `'C:/Users/Path/{}.xls'.format(filename)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  input= "C:/Users/Path/" + user_input + ".xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, 
               sheetname=sheet, 
               header=0,
               parse_cols="C:BD",
               na_values='T')
```

or What i did is, i used library glob

```
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/Path/*')
for file in files:
    input = input('Use ' + file + '?')
    if input == y or input == yes:
        sheet = input('Sheet name?')
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, 
               sheetname=sheet, 
               header=0,
               parse_cols="C:BD",
               na_values='T')
```